# When using a square root transformation on negatively skewed data, how do you return the original value?

Tags: r, transformation, square-root, data-transform

I had some data that was negatively skewed in r. The transformation I used was: sqrt(max(x+1)-x) from this website: https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/transform-data-to-normal-distribution-in-r/. The transformation worked well and normalised the data. I ran the data through a linear model and the estimated marginal means were produced. My question is how do I return the transformed data to the original data. For example:

```
x=c(11:20)
z=sqrt(max(x+1)-x)
```

The 'x' output is: [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

The 'z' output is:[1] 3.162278 3.000000 2.828427 2.645751 2.449490 2.236068 2.000000 1.732051 1.414214 1.000000

What code would return 'z' to 'x'?

Thanks

Oliver

Comment: Do you know `max(x+1)`? In this case `21 - z^2` might work.

Comment: min(z^2 - 1) + x

Answer (score 0):

GKi's comment seems to work.

```
max(x)-z^2
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32934468)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Nobody answered the question they were all comments?